# Where should I use "told" and "said"?

Tags: early-modern-english

Please let me know weather the following sentences are correct :

1. Jessica never told me she having a sister .
2. They told me to stop playing video game.
3. She said you guys making a trip to Canada.

Comment: I'm letting you know that only sentence #2 sounds correct.

Comment: None of them sound correct to me. In #2 “video game” would have to be plural.

Comment: **weather** should be **whether**. No. 2 needs to be "video **games**" with a plural or it needs to be "**the** video game" if not plural.  No. 3 needs "are" between "you guys" and "making".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is too much here to explain. I'll keep it short:

1. We use **say** and **tell** in different ways in reported speech. **Say** focuses on the words someone said and **tell** focuses more on the content or message of what someone said.
2. We use **say** with direct speech. We don’t normally use **tell** in this way.
3. Both **say** and **tell** take *a direct object*. The object is most commonly the *reported clause* (the report of what someone said).
4. **Tell** normally takes an *indirect object* (one or more people = io) and *a direct object* (the reported clause = do). However, we use **tell** without *an indirect object* with words such as *the truth*, *a lie*, *a joke*, *a story*.
5. **Say** does not take *an indirect object*. Instead, we use a phrase with *to*.
6. We use **tell** with *an indirect object* and a *to-infinitive* to report a command or an instruction. We don’t normally use **say** in this way.
7. But in informal speaking, we sometimes use **say** + *to-infinitive* to report a command or an instruction.

Typical errors.

1. We don’t use *an indirect object* with **say**.
2. We don’t use **tell** without *an indirect object* when we report someone’s words.

---

Reference:

- [Cambridge Dictionary - Say or tell?](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/say-or-tell)